# Getting More Than 20 Products To Show On Live Search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, filter, autocomplete

Using a live search feature on a wordpress website, instead of the built in wordpress search.

This live search only returns 20 products on each search.

Trying to figure out how we can get more than 20 products to show, as there are normally a lot more than 20 products that can be shown on each individual search.

Code below that we are trying to tweak:

```
function wpsc_live_search() {
if ( version_compare( get_option ( 'wpsc_version' ), 3.8, '<' ) ) {
    $autocomplete = 'onkeyup="autocomplete(event)"';
} else {
    $autocomplete = '';
}
//get the url to submit the search to
$product_page_id = wpsc_get_the_post_id_by_shortcode( '[productspage]' );
$pp_url = get_permalink( $product_page_id );
// the js below listens for the enter keypress and redirects to the product page with a get 
var of the search term
?>
<div class="live_search_form">
<input name="product_search" id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" <?php echo $autocomplete; ?> 
class="wpsc_live_search" autocomplete="off" />
<script type='text/javascript' > /* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery('#wpsc_search_autocomplete').keypress( function(e){
if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
var url = '<?php echo $pp_url ?>'+'?product_search='+jQuery(this).val();
url = encodeURI(url);
jQuery(window.location).attr('href', url);
}
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
<div class="blind_down" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<?php   
}
```

Does anyone know how the above code could be tweaked, or better still a filter that could be
applied to functions.php of the active theme, which would enable more than 20 products to
show? Ideally it would be good to be able to either return all the products applicable to each
search, or prehaps set a maximum number of 40 products to display for any given search?

Comment: Using the `pre_get_posts` filter to set a different `post_per_page` value for the query should probably work, https://mubashir09.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-limit-number-products-search-results-page/

Comment: In the plugin settings you have search limit field - type anything between 1 and 500 (limited by the plugin).

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for your message. 20 items are returned on every search, when you type any number between 1 - 500.